# How can I use all endpoints with service reference In WCF?

Tags: wcf, binding, wcf-endpoint

I write my service with multiple binding.And I use 2 baseadress and I create 3 end points for tcp and 3 end points for http.How can I use all endpoints with service reference in client app?Is it enough to add base adress to service reference?

Comment: are you talking about add service reference in VS?

Comment: No if you have then as 3 different services then you would need to add 3 different service references as each service would have a different wsdl? Would be more easy if you can post a sample config on what you intend to have

Comment: @Rajesh I guess he has only one service

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have only one service which exposes three contracts, then you would have to have for each contract an defined endpoint. In your case, because you are using two bindings basicHttp and tcp you will have three for each binding type. I don't see the point of referencing the endpoints for both bindings in your client application. Is this a API library or something? If that is the case I recommend you to use the channel factory in order to build your client proxies manually, svcutil.exe will cause you trouble in this scenario.